# react material-ui 11.1 theme documentation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

this may seem like a somewhat silly question, but where can I find the documentation for themes in material-ui 11.1? the docs just changed on their home site to 12.1, but I am still using 11.1 and at the moment my team and I are locked into that version for an app I we're creating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are in the main repo under /Docs, so you could check out the 11.1 release and run locally to browse the docs, or just read the source: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/b55b770f2049852febe47bef27aa0eaceafcec08/docs%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fpages%2Fcustomization%2Fthemes.jsx?ts=4

To [browse the docs locally](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/docs) for v11.1 :

```
git clone git@github.com:callemall/material-ui.git
cd material-ui
git checkout v0.11.1
npm install
cd docs
npm install
npm start
```

Then open http://localhost:3000

Comment: yeah I figured it out awhile back just didn't get around to answering it, but thanks. this answer will definitely help people.